# Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, 20.10

After I forcefully turned System off, and then Turned on tomorrow morning, I got :-

*Failed to start default target:
Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in the transaction.*

Ubuntu 20. There were no updates and i was running it fine since last 2 months.
Ive tried using nomodeset but got same. In terminal, I dont see my user directory in home folder.
I dont think it has something to do with UEFI as i was running it fine. Windows runs fine tho.

Can you help me understand the issue, it seems like a race condition to me.

System: Asus FX504GE , intel, Nvidia

**Update:** After investigating logs, I found that error occured in filesystem of **home** folder:-

```
[FAILED] Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/ <disk id>
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I finally found it. It was due to error in my file system after I saw logs.
Simple solution was to run:

```
$ fsck /dev/diskname
```

In my case my home was on /dev/sda3.

But till I found solution, I had reinstalled ubuntu. I encountered same error while using the old home partition, so I issued above command. It worked!

Comment: Cheers - saved my bacon there you did

Comment: Having a similar issue after a power outage. Trying fsck, but not sure if it's going to work considering my combination of ext4, btrfs, and zfs on this machine. It's saying for some disks I need to try btrfs check, which seems to be doing something... Will report back later. I'm hopeful my bacon will also be saved.

Comment: Few, well that was a wild journey. I got it fixed. I'm not sure exactly what steps fixed it, but here is a lit of things I did. I had to boot with a live-disk to run fsck on my boot drive, which did fix some errors. But I also had an issue in my /etc/fstab that the disk paths like /dev/nvme0n1p1 were pointing to the wrong places so I had to switch them to /dev/disk/by-id/... variants. But my bacon is officially saved!