# Cannot boot Ubuntu 22.04 after update: Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target is destructive

Tags: boot, kernel, snap, udev

Good morning,

Since a couple of days I need to boot with advanced configuration to switch from 22.04.3, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic to 22.04.3, with Linux 5.19.0-50-generic.

When I try to switch back to 6.2.0 I get the following error while in emergency mode:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction)
```

- I tried to fsck some disks (nvme0n1p1/nvme0n1p3) but without success.
- I tried to check snap packages status.
- I tried adding UUID to fstab, and setting noauto option.

From *journalctl -b* I get few meaningful errors:

```
journalctl -b | grep failed                                                                                                                                         
août 10 08:46:16 host kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
août 10 08:46:16 host kernel: pci 10000:e0:06.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
août 10 08:46:16 host systemd-udevd[2233]: nvme0n1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:16 host systemd-udevd[2278]: nvme0n1p2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p2' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:16 host systemd-udevd[2233]: nvme0n1p3: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p3' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:16 host systemd-udevd[2279]: nvme0n1p4: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p4' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:16 host systemd-udevd[2236]: nvme0n1p1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1p1' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:17 host systemd-udevd[2249]: zd0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/zd0' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:17 host systemd-udevd[2277]: dm-0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/dm-0' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:17 host systemd-udevd[2259]: dm-1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/dm-1' failed with exit code 1.
août 10 08:46:17 host kernel: thermal thermal_zone13: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
août 10 08:46:22 host systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
août 10 08:46:22 host systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
août 10 08:46:22 host udisksd[3352]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
août 10 08:46:22 host boltd[3611]: [754f8780-9009-domain0                    ] udev: failed to determine if uid is stable: unknown NHI PCI id '0x463e'
août 10 08:46:22 host dbus-daemon[3292]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service not found.
août 10 08:46:22 host containerd[3727]: time="2023-08-10T08:46:22.565379074+02:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
août 10 08:46:22 host containerd[3727]: time="2023-08-10T08:46:22.565653809+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
août 10 08:46:22 host containerd[3727]: time="2023-08-10T08:46:22.572246862+02:00" level=error msg="failed to initialize a tracing processor \"otlp\"" error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
août 10 08:46:22 host NetworkManager[3295]: <info>  [1691649982.7771] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
août 10 08:46:28 host systemd[1]: Started Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
août 10 08:46:32 host gnome-session[4938]: gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 10 08:46:32 host gnome-session[4938]: gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 10 08:46:32 host gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 10 08:46:32 host gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 10 08:46:33 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5031]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:33 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5031]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:34 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5320]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:34 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5320]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
août 10 08:46:34 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5320]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:34 host org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5320]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
août 10 08:46:35 host /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session[4926]: dbus-daemon[4926]: [session uid=127 pid=4926] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
août 10 08:46:47 host gnome-shell[6091]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:47 host gnome-shell[6091]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:48 host systemd[5808]: Dependency failed for GNOME XSettings service.
août 10 08:46:48 host systemd[5808]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Job org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
août 10 08:46:48 host systemd[5808]: gnome-session-x11-services-ready.target: Job gnome-session-x11-services-ready.target/verify-active failed with result 'dependency'.
août 10 08:46:48 host gnome-shell[6936]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:48 host gnome-shell[6936]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
août 10 08:46:48 host gnome-shell[6936]: nvc0_screen_create:1093 - Base screen init failed: -19
août 10 08:46:48 host gnome-shell[6936]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
août 10 08:46:49 host gnome-session[4938]: gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
août 10 08:46:49 host gnome-session-binary[4938]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
août 10 08:46:49 host gdm-launch-environment][4826]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
août 10 08:46:49 host gsd-color[6363]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sharp_Corporation_gdm_127
août 10 08:46:49 host chrome-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[6449]: libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
août 10 08:46:49 host gnome-shell[6091]: clutter_actor_iter_next: assertion 'ri->age == ri->root->priv->age' failed
août 10 08:46:49 host fwupd[8605]: 06:46:49:0981 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
août 10 08:46:49 host fwupd[8605]: 06:46:49:0982 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
août 10 08:46:50 host fwupd[8605]: 06:46:50:0381 FuEngine             failed to add device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.5/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/mtd/mtd0ro: attribute size returned no data
août 10 08:46:53 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: failed to build result for a45df35ac0e948ee180fe216a5f703f32dda163f
août 10 08:47:21 host chrome-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[6449]: [7490:7490:0810/084721.952174:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
août 10 08:47:21 host chrome-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[6449]: [7490:7490:0810/084721.965635:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
août 10 08:47:21 host chrome-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop[6449]: [7490:7490:0810/084721.983039:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
août 10 08:47:32 host PackageKit[5351]: refresh-cache transaction /487_dbdabdde from uid 1000 finished with failed after 38251ms
août 10 08:47:32 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error download-failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
août 10 08:47:50 host update-notifier[11261]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
août 10 08:47:50 host update-notifier[11261]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
août 10 08:48:10 host PackageKit[5351]: refresh-cache transaction /488_eacbebee from uid 1000 finished with failed after 38112ms
août 10 08:48:10 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error download-failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
août 10 08:48:12 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action get-popular: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/find?architecture=amd64&category=featured&confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=base%2Cconfinement%2Clinks%2Ccontact%2Cdescription%2Cdownload%2Clicense%2Cprices%2Cprivate%2Cpublisher%2Crevision%2Csummary%2Ctitle%2Ctype%2Cversion%2Cwebsite%2Cstore-url%2Cmedia%2Ccommon-ids%2Cchannel: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
août 10 08:48:12 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
août 10 08:48:12 host snap-store[6539]: failed to get categories: no categories to show
août 10 08:48:12 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action get-categories: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
août 10 08:48:19 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action get-featured: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/find?architecture=amd64&category=featured&confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=base%2Cconfinement%2Clinks%2Ccontact%2Cdescription%2Cdownload%2Clicense%2Cprices%2Cprivate%2Cpublisher%2Crevision%2Csummary%2Ctitle%2Ctype%2Cversion%2Cwebsite%2Cstore-url%2Cmedia%2Ccommon-ids%2Cchannel: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
août 10 08:48:20 host snap-store[6539]: not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
août 10 08:51:18 host systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
août 10 08:51:18 host systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
août 10 10:03:28 host gnome-shell[6091]: meta_window_set_stack_position_no_sync: assertion 'window->stack_position >= 0' failed
```

Some posts suggest checking */etc/fstab* and *blkid*, but those seem fine:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=9389-007B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
/boot/efi/grub  /boot/grub  none    defaults,bind   0   0
/dev/mapper/cryptoswap  none    swap    sw  0   0
```

*blkid*

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="bpool" UUID="13385049239347291991" UUID_SUB="1576812308839022993" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="49f2d48a-a2e8-eb45-8226-29f2df43dfb8"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="9389-007B" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="2f774651-5934-4b26-bc4f-78beacd56ef7"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="rpool" UUID="1067623568353702806" UUID_SUB="713734070456525173" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="cc230922-b98e-8740-8c41-ee4bb34ba5b9"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="6428d317-d47e-47b9-b48a-e0e779db6381" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="98bfd493-ed0d-7845-abb1-e8afa520d3b5"
/dev/mapper/keystore-rpool: LABEL="keystore-rpool" UUID="30d1ce58-d747-4132-883e-85550a2c5f9b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

For now I can still boot with old kernel, but it is a bit tedious to go through emergency mode then advanced configuration at every boot.

Any idea of what could be the culprit?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day everyone.

EDIT: Cannot post full update log so I picked few lines:

```
2023-08-08 09:21:11 upgrade base-files:amd64 12ubuntu4.3 12ubuntu4.4
...
2023-08-08 09:21:24 upgrade firefox:amd64 116.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 116.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
...
2023-08-08 09:26:11 status installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic:amd64 6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1
...
2023-08-08 09:39:41 remove linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic:amd64 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 <none>
...
2023-08-08 09:39:43 remove linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic:amd64 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 <none>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ubuntu-desktop" disappear on reboot (Ubuntu 22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481221/ubuntu-desktop-disappear-on-reboot-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319227/transaction-for-graphical-target-start-is-destructive)

Comment: As mentionned already tried fsck.
Plus ubuntu-desktop is still present as I can launch the UI in recovery mode with kernel 6.20.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same message and the GUI did noch start (ubuntu 22.0.4):
graphical.target/start is destructive emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included...

It seems this message is missleading, in my case I had still the 'wrong' boot order set to USB Device set in the first order - normal woud be HDD!  Changing the boot order to HDD in the first place soved the problem, without further action.